# Speed Limit Data For ArcGIS: Metro Atlanta Region

Tags: geospatial, transportation

Working on a project to determine the speed limits of every road network within Metro Atlanta's boundary. I have GDOT RC data, Navteq/HERE data, ABM data made in-house, and Open Street Maps. These all differ a bit. Where can I find, or pull, the data to get closer to the completion of my project?

Comment: Could you confirm that the ABM data stands for Activity Based Model? Also, which version of ArcGIS do you have?

Comment: ABM is activity based model. It is ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a hierarchy of speed limits. The NavTeq/Here data will include all roadway databases; starting with this, then you can spatially join the data to the base network you create.

The key will be determining which database you "trust" more.